# Goodix Fingerprint Reader driver issues

Tags: 12.04, drivers, fingerprint-reader

I have already tried installing Fingerprint GUI and `fprint-demo`. None of them detects the fingerprint reader on my device, which works fine on Windows.

Here are my laptop's specifications:
*Device: Lenovo Ideapad S540

Fingerprint Reader: Goodix

Hardware: Goodix Fingerprint SGX*

Answer (score 1):

currently there are no drivers available for linux. there is work being done but no good progress so far.
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=27c6